# Absolute network path to CSS file in HTML?

Tags: java, html, css

I maintain a small ERP system written in Java; this application creates XHTML reports, which are styled with CSS sheets stored in a central directory on a file server. This is in a heterogeneous environment: Linux, Windows and various browsers. Generating an appropriate link to the CSS file turns out to be difficult. The CSS file should be referenced like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file:/server/path/to/file.css" />
```

This is generated using File.toURI() in Java, however, it does not work under Windows. What *does* work turns out to vary wildly by browser and operating system:

- Under Linux the "file:" protocol is optional. You can begin the path with 1, 3, 4 or 5 slashes (but not 2). This is the same for Chromium and Firefox.
- Under Windows, if you omit the "file:", then IE insists on exactly 2 slashes to start the path, but Firefox insists on exactly 5 slashes. If you include the "file:" protocol, then IE will accept 2, 4 or 5 slashes; Firefox still wants exactly 5 slashes.

So the only variant that seems to work across all systems and browsers is

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file://///server/path/to/file.css" />
```

The explanation for this, as near as I can imagine: three slashes in a URI indicate a context on the local file system. A windows network path would begin with two backslashes, but backslashes aren't allowed in URIs, so they apparently become two additional forward slashes.

Nothing like this appears in the [URI syntax specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986). There's no easy way to generate bizarre URIs like this either - you've got to add the extra slashes yourself.

I feel like there's got to be a better way to deal with links to local resources in a platform-independent way. What am I missing?

Comment: can you use relative path?

Comment: Not easily: the reports are generated on local clients,  but the CSS files are on a central file server. Copying the CSS files to every client would be possible, but has obvious drawbacks.

Comment: A small addendum: I've just realized that File.toURI().toString() generates different results under Linux and under Windows. Neither result contains the required five slashes, but this OS-dependency makes a hard-coded fix more complex than expected.

Answer (score 1):

If someone else eventually posts a better answer, I'll accept that. In the meantime, here is the workaround I have come up with (in Java). The point is to produce a URI that always begins with "file://///".

```
/**
     * This method produces a URI than can be embedded in HTML to reference a file in the local
     * network, for example, a CSS file. The only format that seems to work across browsers and
     * operating systems is one containing five slashes, i.e., file://///server/path/to/file.css.
     * Firefox is the most difficult browser to please, particularly under Windows.
     * 
     * Note that the toString() and getPath() methods of the URI object product different results
     * depending on the operating system; hence, we must remove all slashes from the start of the
     * path, before adding what we want.
     * 
     * @param fileIn
     *            A file object referencing the file
     * @return A string that can be embedded as a URI in an HTML file
     */
    private String fixHtmlUri(File fileIn) {
        URI uri = fileIn.toURI();
        String path = uri.getPath();

        // Remove all slashes from the beginning of the path
        int numSlashesAtStart = 0;
        while (path.charAt(numSlashesAtStart) == '/') numSlashesAtStart++;
        String strippedUriString = path.substring(numSlashesAtStart);

        // Add the require five slashes plus the file protocol
        return "file://///" + strippedUriString;
    }
```